# Non-destructive substitute on regex capture variables broken in perl5?

Tags: regex, substitution, perl

I've noticed a behaviour which looks fishy to me. Verified for sure on perl 5.18 and perl 5.22.

A simplified one-liner below to illustrate.

```
$ echo -e "A B C D\n# E F G" | perl -wnE 'm{(.) (.) (.) (.)}; say($1,$2,$3,$4); say "HELLO $1 " . ($1 =~ s/\w/###/r) ." $2 $3 $4"'
ABCD
Use of uninitialized value $2 in concatenation (.) or string at -e line 1, <> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $3 in concatenation (.) or string at -e line 1, <> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $4 in concatenation (.) or string at -e line 1, <> line 1.
HELLO A ###   
#EFG
HELLO # # E F G
```

Apparently calling a non-destructive substitution on any capture-related variable undefines or in some way prevent access to any previously defined capture-related variables. Same thing when using named captures and the `%+` hash.

That seems like a bug to me, but I don't know whether I am missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html): *"Capture group contents are dynamically scoped and available to you outside the pattern until the end of the enclosing block or until the next successful match, whichever comes first."*

Comment: @sln: No, unsuccessful match wouldn't clear them.

Comment: @choroba - when it parses `=~` the variables are immediately cleared.

Comment: @choroba: correct. In the original code the error came up only with successful matches for the substitution.

Comment: @sln: Do you mean `"a" !~ /\w/`? No match, no clearing: `perl -wE '"a" =~ /(.)/; say $1; "b" =~ /x/; say $1'`

Comment: Code in the original question changed
@sln this seems to prove otherwise

Comment: Ok, the $1 persists past the parse and is the target of the next regex, so, I'm stumped. But @choroba is correct, the vars are only cleard/re-populated on a successful match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [perlvar](http://p3rl.org/perlvar):

> Perl sets these variables when it has a successful match

So, any successful matching would clear the values, it's not relevant that the match variable itself is subject to the matching.

Comment: Staring at me right in the face, silly me. For some reason I had not mentally associated the substitution with a new match.
Thank you.